# can we always decompose a joint probability distribution into the product of a conditional distribution and a marginal distribution?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, conditional-probability

Let $P$ be an underlying probability measure and $X_1,X_2$ be two random variables. Denote by $P^{(X_1,X_2)}$ the joint distribution of $(X_1,X_2)$ under $P$, $P^{X1}$ the marginal distribution of $X_1$ and $P^{X_2 | X_1}$ the conditional distribution of $X_2$ conditionally to $X_1$.
Can we always write $\mathrm{d}P^{X_2 | X_1}\mathrm{d}P^{X1}=\mathrm{d}P^{(X_1,X_2)}$ ?

Comment: What is the formal definition of those differentials like $dP^{X_1}$?

Comment: Note that if $f$ is a measurable function and $E[|f(X_1,X_2)|]<\infty$ then you can always do $$E[f(X_1,X_2)]=E[E[f(X_1,X_2)|X_1]]$$ which may be what you really want anyway.

Comment: I probably shouldn't have written it this way, essentially I want to know if I can always write the joint distribution as the product measure of a conditional distribution and the marginal distribution. I think that I need to do that to prove a chain rule for kullback leibler divergences which is stated here : https://ibb.co/ZY5tTgW